# Calendar not returning GMT

Tags: android, calendar, gmt

I am trying to get a calendar object set to GMT, but the getTime() always returns the time in GMT+1 (my current time). I have tried:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("skeniver"));
```

They all apparently return GMT, because

```
cal.getTimeZone().getDisplayName()
```

returns "GMT+00:00"; but

```
cal.getTime().toString();
```

always displays the time in GMT+1.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to in string then prefer the DateFormat or SimpleDateFormat for this

here is example

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(); // here you can also define your format of date for e.g. "dd/MM/yyyy z"

sdf.setTimeZone("GMT");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust for daylight savings. I'm not sure if this will help but it's code I use for adjusting any timezone to UTC in an app that's currently being used by a number of people around the world. I use `Date` instead of `Calendar` but it works...

```
Date dateTimeNow = new Date();
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
int currentOffsetFromUTC = tz.getRawOffset() + (tz.inDaylightTime(dateTimeNow) ? tz.getDSTSavings() : 0);
Date dateTimeNowUTC = new Date(dateTimeNow.getTime() - currentOffsetFromUTC);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.getTime()` returns a `Date` object. In Java, a `Date` is just a holder to a long timestamp starting in the UNIX epoch.

To display a `Date` in a different `TimeZone` than the default, you can use a `SimpleDateFormat`.